How to call wp-load.php from patterns folder
In function.php
function register_custom_patterns() {
    register_block_pattern(
        'twentytwentyfive/asif', // The pattern slug
        array(
            'title'       => __( 'Test Pattern', 'twentytwentyfive' ),
            'description' => __( 'A custom test pattern for the theme.', 'twentytwentyfive' ),
            'content'     => file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri() . '/patterns/asif.php'), // Path to your custom PHP file
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_patterns' );

Location of asif.php file
C:\xampp\htdocs\asif_wp\wp-content\themes\twentytwentyfive\patterns\asif.php
asif.php  code
   function asif() {
       echo "Working!";
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'asif' );

After loading Test Pattern in theme
Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\xampp\htdocs\asif_wp\wp-content\themes\twentytwentyfive\patterns\asif.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\asif_wp\wp-content\themes\twentytwentyfive\patterns\asif.php on line 6    

Then I edited asif.php
<?php
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
function asif() {
   echo "Working!";
}
add_action( 'init', 'asif' );

?>

Result:
Browser is loading (waiting)  and passing through infinite loop and at the end my computer is hanging

I guess you found the solution to your problem as you posted a new question related to the same code. Did you manage to load wp-load?

The short answer is "you don't". Looking very specifically at this code, your pattern is called during the init hook already, so it is nonsensical to register an additional init hook in this file, you are already there. If this is related to your previous question, then you might be doing something the hard way. Generally, calling "wp-load.php" means "boot a dedicated copy of WordPress", and it is rare that you'd want to do that while "inside" WordPress already.
